# Using java-apns, can switching certificate for multiple apps be considered for denial of service?

Tags: push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications, handshake, reconnect

When using java APNs, if using the same program to send messages to different applications, it is required to use different certificates. Does switching certificates causes disconnection/reconnection and is it considered a bad practice? (as APNs would like to have persistent connections thus preventing denial of service).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to switch a certificate for an existing connection. At least I'm quite sure it's not possible in Java `SSLSocket` (since it is constructed by an `SSLSocketFactory`, and you use the certificate in one of the parameters required for constructing that factory).

You should maintain an open socket for each application you are sending notifications to. This way you don't have to close the socket and open a new one each time you need to switch certificates.